# how to calculate E[vech(x x')vech(x x')']?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, inference, information-theory, fisher-information

Supposing a vector x follows normal distribution. I want to calculate the expectation of the "fourth moment" in a vector form, meaning $\text{E}[\text{vech}(x x')\text{vech}(x x')']$, given that we know $\text{E}[x x'] = S$ and the expectation of $x$ is a zero vector. This is a piece of a Fisher information matrix.

Anyone can give me some suggestion on how to get that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The multivariate normal central moment generating function is $\exp(t'St/2)$,
from which it follows that the mixed fourth central moments are 
(in two different notations):

$m_{22} = m_{20} m_{02} + 2 m_{11}^2  $

$\quad\quad = s_{1122} = s_{11} s_{22} + 2 s_{12}^2 = s_{1}^2 s_{2}^2 (1 + 2 r_{12}^2)$

$m_{31} = 3 m_{20} m_{11} $

$\quad\quad = s_{1112} = 3 s_{11} s_{12} = 3 s_{1}^3 s_{2} r_{12}$

$m_{211} = m_{200} m_{011} + 2 m_{110} m_{101}  $

$\quad\quad\,\, = s_{1123} = s_{11} s_{23} + 2 s_{12} s_{13} = s_{1}^2 s_{2} s_{3} (r_{23} + 2 r_{12} r_{13})$

$m_{1111}\,\, = m_{1100} m_{0011} + m_{1010} m_{0101} + m_{1001} m_{0110}  $

$\quad\quad\quad = s_{1234} = s_{12} s_{34} + s_{13} s_{24} + s_{14} s_{23} = s_1 s_2 s_3 s_4 (r_{12} r_{34} + r_{13} r_{24} + r_{14} r_{23})$

Comment: probably worthwhile to note that to use mgf you need to take fourth order derivative of $\exp(t^TSt/2)$ and set $t=0$.